# Cannot publish Django Rest API on heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to publish my Django rest framework application to Heroku. I'm following all the procedures accordingly to publish from Github repository but don't know where is my mistake. In Heroku deploy tab it says deployed successfully but while i go to visit the page it show the following error.

[image: Heroku error page once visit button is pressed]

My folder structure is as follows where my API is in api folder and the project is in config folder:

[image]

I've specified the file name in Heroku procfile as follows (adding asgi file since my project is using asgi instade of wsgi for Django channels):

```
web: gunicorn config.asgi --log-file -
```

When I check the error from the terminal it cannot find module config but also show build success.
The error is as follows:

```
2021-01-14T07:10:10.612461+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-01-14T07:10:25.885018+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn config.asgi --log-file -`
2021-01-14T07:10:30.278347+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-14 07:10:30 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
2021-01-14T07:10:30.279496+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-14 07:10:30 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:36267 (4)
2021-01-14T07:10:30.279664+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-14 07:10:30 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2021-01-14T07:10:30.296521+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-14 07:10:30 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2021-01-14T07:10:30.305338+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-01-14T07:10:30.310836+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-14 07:10:30 +0000] [9] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2021-01-14T07:10:30.310838+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-01-14T07:10:30.310839+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2021-01-14T07:10:30.310839+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2021-01-14T07:10:30.310839+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
2021-01-14T07:10:30.310840+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2021-01-14T07:10:30.310840+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
2021-01-14T07:10:30.310841+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2021-01-14T07:10:30.310841+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2021-01-14T07:10:30.310842+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2021-01-14T07:10:30.310842+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
2021-01-14T07:10:30.310843+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2021-01-14T07:10:30.310843+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
2021-01-14T07:10:30.310844+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2021-01-14T07:10:30.310844+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
2021-01-14T07:10:30.310844+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2021-01-14T07:10:30.310845+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2021-01-14T07:10:30.310845+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-01-14T07:10:30.310846+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
2021-01-14T07:10:30.310850+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
2021-01-14T07:10:30.310850+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-01-14T07:10:30.310851+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2021-01-14T07:10:30.310851+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
2021-01-14T07:10:30.310852+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
2021-01-14T07:10:30.310852+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-01-14T07:10:30.310891+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'
2021-01-14T07:10:30.311499+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-14 07:10:30 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2021-01-14T07:10:30.315154+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-14 07:10:30 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2021-01-14T07:10:30.327640+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-14 07:10:30 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2021-01-14T07:10:30.327642+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-01-14T07:10:30.327643+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2021-01-14T07:10:30.327646+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2021-01-14T07:10:30.327647+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
2021-01-14T07:10:30.327647+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2021-01-14T07:10:30.327648+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
2021-01-14T07:10:30.327648+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2021-01-14T07:10:30.327649+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2021-01-14T07:10:30.327649+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2021-01-14T07:10:30.327650+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
2021-01-14T07:10:30.327650+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2021-01-14T07:10:30.327650+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
2021-01-14T07:10:30.327651+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2021-01-14T07:10:30.327651+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
2021-01-14T07:10:30.327652+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2021-01-14T07:10:30.327652+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2021-01-14T07:10:30.327652+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-01-14T07:10:30.327653+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
2021-01-14T07:10:30.327653+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
2021-01-14T07:10:30.327654+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-01-14T07:10:30.327654+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2021-01-14T07:10:30.327655+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
2021-01-14T07:10:30.327655+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
2021-01-14T07:10:30.327655+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-01-14T07:10:30.327662+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'
2021-01-14T07:10:30.330406+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-14 07:10:30 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2021-01-14T07:10:30.699256+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-14 07:10:30 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2021-01-14T07:10:30.699284+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-14 07:10:30 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2021-01-14T07:10:30.841732+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2021-01-14T07:10:30.899896+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2021-01-14T07:10:34.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-01-14T07:10:38.414171+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=bdops.herokuapp.com request_id=82351dfb-0fc1-4ac9-8cb7-d11da59d8b1c fwd="103.106.33.81" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```